# Como incrementar o valor de uma variável de acordo com a resposta do usuário?

Tags: python

Gostaria de fazer uma pergunta ao usuário para ele responder "sim" ou "não". Se a resposta for "sim" adicionar 10 pesos a variável `peso` e se for "não", não adicionar.

Estou com uma dúvida em como converter a *string* para inteiro.

```
fotossenbilidade = input('Você tem sensibilidade com relação a luz?')
```

O usuário teria que responder "sim" ou "não", como faço para adicionar essas opções? E para adicionar os pesos eu teria que utilizar um `if`?

Comment: Converter para inteiro basta fazer `valor = int(string_a_converter)`. O que quer dizer com adicionar pesos?

Answer (score 4):

Quando você precisa solicitar algo do usuário e validar a informação, é natural que não saibamos quantas vezes o usuário irá precisar até entrar com uma informação válida. Pode existir o usuário que responderá corretamente na primeira, mas pode existir aquele que levará dezenas de tentativas. Isso nos indica que o código deverá ser baseado em um laço de repetição infinito e pará-lo somente quando o usuário responder corretamente "sim" ou "não". O código que sugiro é:

```
peso = 0

while True:
    resposta = input('Você tem sensibilidade à luz? [sim|não] ').lower()
    if resposta not in {'sim', 'não'}:
        continue
    if resposta == 'sim':
        peso += 10
    break

print('Peso:', peso)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ActiveLastingCicada)</sup>

**Explicando**

- Definimos a variável `peso` como zero;
- Iniciamos um laço de repetição infinito;
- Solicitamos ao usuário a resposta, convertendo para caixa baixa para facilitar a comparação;
- Verificamos se a resposta foi "sim" ou "não". Se não, continua o laço solicitando ao usuário novamente;
- Se sim, verificamos se a resposta é "sim". Se sim, incrementamos `peso` em 10;
- Encerramos o laço de repetição;
- Exibimos o valor final de `peso`;

**E por que esta solução seria melhor?**

Aproveitando que já tem uma resposta, podemos compará-las.

1. Usando o laço infinito conseguimos solicitar ao usuário apenas uma vez no código; usar várias vezes o `input` para a mesma função é repetir desnecessariamente código.
2. Ao converter para caixa baixa facilitamos as comparações, pois basta verificar se é igual a "sim" ou "não", mesmo que o usuário digite qualquer variação: "SIM", "Sim", "sIm", "Não", "NÃO", etc.
3. Utilizar o operador `in` para verificar a resposta elimina a necessidade de múltiplos operadores lógicos. Definindo os valores entre chaves utilizamos um conjunto, o que praticamente não interfere na performance do código, [pois terá acesso O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306024/5878).
4. É interessante utilizar o operador `+=` para incrementar o valor de `peso` ao invés de defini-lo como 10, pois, se a variável tiver um valor inicial diferente de zero.

---

Outra forma seria criar um dicionário relacionando a resposta do usuário com o valor que deverá ser incrementado em `peso`:

```
incrementos = {
    'sim': 10,
    'não': 0
}
```

E fazer:

```
peso = 0

while True:
    resposta = input('Você tem sensibilidade à luz? [sim|não] ').lower()
    incremento = incrementos.get(resposta, None)
    if incremento is None:
        continue
    peso += incremento
    break

print('Peso:', peso)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BarrenObviousTransversal)</sup>

Se a resposta não existir no dicionário será retornado `None` e continuado o laço até que o usuário entre com um valor válido.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda e a explicação, era exatamente isso que tinha dúvida.

Comment: @JSouza Favor [aceitar esta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)

Comment: Para este tipo de casos não é melhor usar case porque sabemos todos os casos possíveis?

Comment: @Pbras Python não possui *switch/cas*, caso seja isso que comentou. Se não, poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tens razão no Python não tens que fazer um array para poder fazer case e não vale a pena complicar aqui. Já não uso python há alguns anos desculpa a confusão.

Comment: @Pbras adicionei uma versão usando dicionário.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim parece funcionar assim, e caso queira mais opções é só adicionar ao dicionário. Mas como ele disse que era novo a programação não queria o confundir muito. Mas se ele perceber fica com mais uma forma de fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um condicional para verificar qual foi o input do usuário!

```
fotossenbilidade = input('Você tem sensibilidade com relação a luz?')
Peso = 0 # inicializa variavel Peso

# loop para garantir que o input do usuário está de acordo com o esperado
while (fotossenbilidade != 'Sim' and fotossenbilidade != 'sim' and fotossenbilidade != 'Nao' and fotossenbilidade != 'nao:'):

    fotossenbilidade = input('Você tem sensibilidade com relação a luz?')

if (fotossenbilidade == 'Sim' or fotossenbilidade == 'sim'):
    Peso = 10
```

Comment: Mas se eu responder Não ele vai gerar um loop infinito e ficar fazendo a mesma pergunta ?

Comment: Não, pelo contrário. Ele faz o loop até receber OU um sim OU um não. Depois ele compara e, caso tenha sido um sim, ele atribui um peso à variável.