# Como pode a busca de um elemento em um conjunto ser O(1)?

Tags: python, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Conforme a [página oficial do Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) quanto à complexidade dos algoritmos no tempo, as sequências `list` e `set` possuem as seguintes características:

## [List](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## [Set](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Destaque para o operador `in`, que verifica a presença de um elemento na sequência, que em `list` possui complexidade O(n) e em `set` possui O(1).

Como pode o operador `in` ter complexidade O(1) em uma sequência?

Comment: Relacionada: [Definição da notação “Big O”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-big-o)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Os conjuntos `set` não são "sequências" - nem na organização interna dos dados, nem na interface que implementam, já que não garantem nenhuma ordem.

Conjuntos na verdade tem a implementação parecida com a de dicionários - mas só o lado da chave: internamente, uma estrutura de dados contendo o `hash` dos objetos é usada, e esta mapeia para uma referência real ao objeto. Então, o "grosso" da busca é pelo hash do objeto nessa estrutura.

[E, buscas por hash são justamente feitas para serem O(1).](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o)

Se o hash é encontrado, a referência do objeto é recuperada - se for o mesmo objeto (id's são mesmo), se dá o match, senão uma comparação por igualdade é feita. Essas outras verificações, e, mesmo no caso de colisão de hash, quando é feita uma busca sequencial entre os objetos de mesmo hash, não contam para a complexidade algoritmica.

Claro que a limitação é que objetos "unhashable" (em geral, objetos mutáveis), não podem ser colocados em conjuntos (sets), assim como não podem ser chaves de dicionários. Se isso for necessário, é necessário implementar uma classe que responda a mesma interface dos conjuntos(veja `collections.abc`), mas com outros algoritmos internos, que dificilmente poderão ser O(1), a não ser que usem uma técnica parecida.

Comment: Este último parágrafo é o que explicaria o *worst case* citado como O(n)?

Comment: SIm - (é o penúltimo parágrafo agora, acrescentei mais um). Mas esse worst case é worst" mesmo - só se todos os objetos no conjunto tivessem o mesmo hash - o hash é de 32/64bits (depende da implementação) e colisões são bem incomuns - se ocorrerem é uma duplicidade no máximo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim. No pior dos casos, todos os elementos vão ficar na mesma célula da tabela de espalhamento