# Como posso melhorar meu código do jogo da forca?

Tags: python, programação-estruturada, game

Quais dicas vocês dariam para melhorar esse código do jogo da forca em Python? No "curso" que estou fazendo de Python ainda não aprendi a usar os métodos de strings ainda. É um jogo da forca bem simples, sem interface gráfica porque não sei fazer e com 5 palavras que usei para testar. O que vocês acham que da para melhorar o código e deixar mais compacto? Obrigado

```
from random import choice

def imprime(letra, pl):
    #imprime como está o resultado do jogo. Exemplo: c _ _ c l e _ _
    impressao = ''
    for i in range(len(palavra)):
        if palavra[i] not in pl:
            impressao += "%s "%palavra[i]
        else:
            impressao += '_ '
    return impressao

#palavras pré-definidas
palavras = ['chiclete', 'arroz', 'banana', 'feijao', 'nutella']

#escolhe a palavra do jogo
palavra = choice(palavras)

erros = 0
pl = []
#adiciona todas as letras da palavra a uma lista 'pl'
for i in range(len(palavra)):
    pl.append(palavra[i])

#imprime a quantidade de letras da palavra
print("A palavra é: %s"%('_ '*len(palavra)))
print("")
jogo = True
tentativas = []

while jogo:

    letra = input("Digite uma letra ou palavra: ")
    #o usuario digita uma letra ou palavra
    if letra == palavra:
        #verifica se o jogador acertou a palavra, caso sim encerra o programa
        print("Você ganhou. A palavra era %s"%palavra)
        break

    #verifica se a letra escolhida ainda não havia sido escolhida pelo usuario
    while letra in tentativas:
        letra = input("Você já tentou essa letra ou palavra. Digite novamente: ")
    tentativas.append(letra)

    if letra in palavra:
        #se o usuario acertou uma letra, ela é removida da lista 'pl'.
        for i in range(palavra.count(letra)):
            pl.remove(letra)
    else:
        erros += 1
        #se o usuario errar a letra ou palavra, é contabilizado um erro. Com 6 erros o usuario é derrotado.
        if erros == 6:
            print("Você errou pela 6ª vez. Fim de jogo")
            print("Você perdeu")
            break

        print("Você errou pela %iª vez. Tente de novo!"%erros)
    print("A palavra é: ",imprime(letra, pl))
    print("")

    if len(pl) == 0:
        #se a lista 'pl' possuir 0 elementos, então o usuario ganhou
        print("Você ganhou!")
        break
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(palavra))` você pode substituir por `for letra in palavra` e usar apenas `letra` no lugar de `palavra[i]`

Comment: deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Se puder fazer isso com os métodos da *string*, existe o método `lower()` para isso.

Comment: Anderson Carlos, se eu for usar variaveis definidas fora da função dentro de uma função mas não irei modifica-las, eu preciso colocar essas variaveis como entrada mesmo assim? Por exemplo, na função "imprime" eu não modifiquei nenhuma variavel que eu chamei, era necessario coloca-la? A variavel 'pl', por exemplo

Answer (score 4):

**Exibindo a palavra na tela**

Primeiro, façamos a função que exibe a palavra na tela, junto com os sublinhados nas letras que não deverão ser exibidas. Para isso, podemos fazer:

```
def exibir(palavra, tentativas):
    caracteres = (letra if letra in tentativas else '_' for letra in palavra)
    return ' '.join(caracteres)
```

Assim, será exibida a palavra, exceto os caracteres que **não** estiverem em `tentativas`, que serão substituídos por um sublinhado, `_`.

```
exibir('woss', [])  # _ _ _ _
exibir('woss', ['s'])  # _ _ s s
exibir('woss', ['s', 'w'])  # w _ s s
exibir('woss', ['s', 'w', 'o'])  # w o s s
```

**Sorteando a palavra**

A parte de sortear qual será a palavra você fez bem e não tem o que mudar:

```
from random import choice

palavras = ['chiclete', 'arroz', 'banana', 'feijao', 'nutella']
palavra = choice(palavras)
```

**Lógica do jogo**

Começamos definindo a quantidade de erros do usuário e as tentativas que ele fez:

```
tentativas = set()
erros = 0
```

Neste ponto, utilizei `tentativas` como sendo um conjunto, pois não fará sentido termos tentativas duplicadas e o conjunto possui otimizações em seu acesso e busca em relação à lista. Neste ponto é quase como uma micro-otimização, mas fica a dica para você estudar.

- [Como pode a busca de um elemento em um conjunto ser O(1)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306024/5878)

Para o laço, você não precisa criar uma variável só para ser verdadeira sempre, pode usar direto o `True`. Bem como você não precisa imprimir a "palavra" fora do laço, faça isso apenas dentro dele e faça apenas uma vez.

```
while True:
    print('A palavra atual é:', exibir(palavra, tentativas))

    while True:
        tentativa = input('Digite uma letra ou palavra: ').lower()
        if tentativa not in tentativas:
            tentativas.add(tentativa)
            break
        print('Você já fez essa tentativa.')
```

Veja que utilizei o método `lower` da *string* para converter a entrada do usuário para minúscula sempre, para não termos que nos preocupar com isso e utilizei outro laço infinito para verificar a entrada do usuário, isso evita que você precise fazer o mesmo `input` duas vezes no código.

Neste ponto, já podemos verificar se o usuário venceu ou não. Isso se dará quando a palavra não possuir mais o caractere `_` ou quando o usuário digitar a palavra inteira corretamente:

```
if '_' not in exibir(palavra, tentativas) or tentativa == palavra:
    print('Você venceu')
    break
```

Mas se o usuário não venceu, devemos verificar se ele pelo menos acertou uma letra ou errou, para então contabilizar os erros.

```
if tentativa not in palavra:
    print(f'Você errou! Só te restam {5-erros} tentativas')
    erros += 1
```

E, por fim, finalizar o jogo quando o usuário atingir as seis tentativas sem sucesso.

```
if erros == 6:
    print('Você perdeu!')
    break
```

**Ficaria mais ou menos assim...**

```
from random import choice

def exibir(palavra, tentativas):
    caracteres = (letra if letra in tentativas else '_' for letra in palavra)
    return ' '.join(caracteres)

palavras = ['chiclete', 'arroz', 'banana', 'feijao', 'nutella']
palavra = choice(palavras)

tentativas = set()
erros = 0

while True:
    print('A palavra atual é:', exibir(palavra, tentativas))

    while True:
        tentativa = input('Digite uma letra ou palavra: ').lower()
        if tentativa not in tentativas:
            tentativas.add(tentativa)
            break
        print('Você já fez essa tentativa.')

    if '_' not in exibir(palavra, tentativas) or tentativa == palavra:
        print('Você venceu')
        break

    if tentativa not in palavra:
        print(f'Você errou! Só te restam {5-erros} tentativas')
        erros += 1

    if erros == 6:
        print('Você perdeu!')
        break
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CuteSaneCopyleft)</sup>

Não tão menor quanto a sua versão, mas consideravelmente mais simples e legível.

Quanto a utilização de *f-string* para formatar uma *string* ao invés do operador `%`, leia:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

Comment: Obrigado. Eu não entendi pra que serve o 'join'. Também não sabia que era possível fazer um for desse jeito: caracteres = (letra if letra in tentativas else '_' for letra in palavra)
Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @BrunoAmaral o `join` une os valores de uma sequência em uma *string* utilizando o caractere como separador. Por exemplo: `'+'.join(['1', '2', '3'])` retornaria `'1+2+3'`.

Comment: Pode me explicar essa linha? Eu ainda não entendi isso:
caracteres = (letra if letra in tentativas else '_' for letra in palavra)

Comment: @BrunoAmaral [Como funciona o comando “for” inline?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240948/5878)