# O que é significa a linha questao += 1 neste código?

Tags: python

Alguém pode me explicar a função da linha `questao +=1`?

Sou iniciante e estou tentando entender a lógica por trás do código e não apenas fazer funcionar.

```
 pontos = 0 questao = 1 while questao <=3:
     resposta = input('Resposta da questão {}: '.format(questao))
     if questao == 1 and resposta == 'b':
         pontos = pontos + 1
     if questao == 2 and resposta == 'a':
         pontos = pontos + 1
     if questao == 3 and resposta == 'd':
         pontos = pontos + 1
     questao +=1 print('O aluno fez {} pontos'.format(pontos))
```

Comment: é uma abreviação de     questao = questao + 1

Comment: Seja bem vindo Daniel, leia esta resposta: [Como incrementar o valor de uma variável de acordo com a resposta do usuário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273353/110782) O problema não é exatamente igual ao seu, mas você entenderá melhor o passo a passo

Comment: Se quiser saber mais do assunto, o nome correto é `OPERADOR DE ATRIBUIÇÃO COMPOSTA` [Operadores compostos em Python](http://excript.com/python/operadores-de-atribuicao-compostos-python.html)

Answer (score 3):

Em resumo, o operador += soma o valor seguinte e adiciona à variável anterior. No caso:

```
questao +=1
```

é (mais ou menos)* equivalente à

```
questao = questao + 1
```

*Não é exatamente equivalente, como @Jefferson Quesado apontou, uma vez que o sinal += em python [substitui o método especial iadd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). Como @hkotsubo sugeriu, para uma explicação mais detalhada da diferença entre as duas formas, [veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402692/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-i-2-e-i-i-2/402702#402702).

Nesse caso, ao executar a linha "questao += 1", a variável questao recebe seu próprio valor atual somado de 1.

Como citado pelo @Luiz Augusto, [mais detalhes podem ser consultados aqui](http://excript.com/python/operadores-de-atribuicao-compostos-python.html).

Para entender o código por completo, é preciso analisar linha a linha:

```
#Variável pontos possui valor 0, questao possui valor 1
pontos = 0
questao = 1

#A instrução while indica que o bloco de código seguinte será executado enquanto questao <= 3.
#Ou seja, cada linha abaixo será percorrida e, ao chegar ao final, será analisado se o valor contido na variável questao é menor ou igual a 3.
#Na primeira vez que esse código é executado, a variável questao possui valor igual a 1, portanto o bloco de código é executado
while questao <=3:

    #A variável resposta recebe o valor do "input".
    #O "input" apresenta ao usuário a frase: 'Resposta da questão {}:', onde {} é substituído pelo valor contido na variável questao.
    #Logo, na primeira execução, "input" apresenta ao usuário a seguinte frase: Resposta da questão 1
    #Após apresentar a frase, "input" aguarda que o usuário digite um valor e aperte enter.
    #O valor digitado é armazenado na variável resposta
    resposta = input('Resposta da questão {}: '.format(questao))

    # O if analisa 2 condições: se o valor da variável questao é igual a 1 e se o valor da variável resposta é igual a b.
    # Caso as duas condições sejam verdadeiras, ele altera o valor da variável pontos para pontos + 1.
    # Caso alguma das condições seja falsa, ele ignora a próxima linha e pula para o próximo if.
    # Detalhe: pontos = pontos + 1 poderia ser reescrito como pontos += 1
    if questao == 1 and resposta == 'b':
        pontos = pontos + 1

    # Aqui o if analisa 2 condições: se o valor da variável questao é igual a 2 e se o valor da variável resposta é igual a a.
    # Caso as duas condições sejam verdadeiras, ele altera o valor da variável pontos para pontos + 1.
    # Caso alguma das condições seja falsa, ele ignora a próxima linha e pula para o próximo if.
    if questao == 2 and resposta == 'a':
        pontos = pontos + 1

    # Aqui o if analisa 2 condições: se o valor da variável questao é igual a 3 e se o valor da variável resposta é igual a d.
    # Caso as duas condições sejam verdadeiras, ele altera o valor da variável pontos para pontos + 1.
    # Caso alguma das condições seja falsa, ele ignora a próxima linha e pula para a linha seguinte.
    if questao == 3 and resposta == 'd':
        pontos = pontos + 1

    # Aqui ele altera o valor da variável questao.
    # Na primeira execução ela irá mudar de 1 para 2.
    # Na segunda execução ela irá mudar de 2 para 3.
    # Na terceira execução ela irá mudar de 3 para 4.
    # Não haverá a quarta execução, pois o while irá notar que o valor da variável questao (3) é não é menor ou igual a 3
    questao +=1

#Por fim, após executar o código dentro do while 3 vezes, ele irá imprimir a frase seguinte, substituindo {} pelo valor contido na variável pontos.
#O valor na variável pontos irá depender dos valores que o usuário digita no input
print('O aluno fez {} pontos'.format(pontos))
```

Comment: "`questao +=1`

é equivalente à

`questao = questao + 1`" alto lá! Isso só é verdade quando o objeto é imutável. Para versões de objetos que aceitam mudanças internas, apesar de o comportamento final ser o mesmo, usar a atribuição somada é mais eficiente. Talvez o melhor seria dizer que são "grosseiramente equivalentes"

Comment: Perfeito! Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Acho que vale colocar um link para [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402702/112052), que explica a diferença com mais detalhes

Comment: Adicionei o link! Essa resposta é bem útil